# Как в delphi лучше сделать печать?

Tags: delphi

Как в delphi лучше сделать печать? Есть шаблон в формате RTF в нём переменные (например: `$name$`). Нужно вместо этих переменных поставить значение из программы и вывести на печать.

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, что ты хочешь печатать: текст или картинки. Но есть и общий для текста и картинок вариант - использовать модуль "printers":

```
> uses printers;
> ...
> function print():boolean; begin
> printer.BeginDoc; // Подготавливаешь к печати принтер
> printer.canvas.textout(10,10,'Halo');  // работаешь с ним, как с обычным canvas
> printer.EndDoc;     //завершаешь печать
> print:=true; 
>end;
```

Comment: в компонентах INDY всё для печати

Comment: Что за чушь! Нет там ничего для печати!